# How to test in and between each of several tables?

Tags: mysql

I know this is too simple for most here, but I just can't figure it out from the 3 books I am using or find it in a tutorial.  They all focus on changing the layout of a database and only give notes about these sort of things.

I was able to create a procedure that activates ever 9 minutes, and the other things it needs to do work fine.

But I just can't find how to do this part.

Table_A

```
(ID, UnitTypeID, ShopLot, )
```

Table_B

```
(ID, UnitTypeID, ShopLot, ContainerRef, )
```

Table_C

```
(ID, PartTypeID, ContainerID, )
```

1. I need to begin by selecting all `UnitTypeID=PAD` in Table_A
2. Then find all instances of `UnitTypeID=FROG` in Table_B that share `ShopLot` with the results from #1
3. Then for each `ContainerRef` fitting #2, check Table_C for `PartTypeID=FLIES` where the `ContainerRef` matches the `ContainerID`

It isn't to do with frogs and flies of course, but it makes for a good relative indication of how the process works.

Once I find a valid 'FLIES' I apply the code below this part and it is done.

If none are found, nothing happens.. and I guess the frog is hungry for 9 more minutes.

(I am open to suggestions for a good query language reference. MySQL sites/videos/tuts all seem to focus almost entirely on data types and database layouts / structural things. Very little about dealing with the actual data)

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called table joins. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Thanks but at this point that looks like a mountain of gibberish with a recognizable word thrown in here and there.
I've been trying for two weeks to learn practical SQL, but I'm stuck at this great void between where I am now, and understanding the entry you linked without any indication where to find the path between.

Answer (score 0):

Well Leonid is right table joins is what you need. "An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them." - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp simple as that. You say for table A and table B that common field is the ShopLot and for table B and C is the ContainerRef matches the ContainerID.

Let's tray do that step by step.

So first lets select columns from the tables we want to show

```
 SELECT Table_A.ID, Table_A.UnitTypeID, Table_A.ShopLot, Table_B.ID, Table_B.UnitTypeID,
         Table_B.ContainerRef, Table_C.ID, Table_C.PartTypeID
```

You see there is only one the ShopLot and the ContainerRef that's becouse that is common field as we said before and there is no need to show the same date twice in one row.

Next step would be to see where FROM we SELECT this columns. In this step we combine rows from this separate tables and basically create one table with all this columns from select statement. That will look like this

```
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.ShopLot = Table_B.ShopLot
INNER JOIN Table_C
ON Table_B.ContainerRef = Table_C.ContainerId
```

What's happened here. First we said SELECT(something) FROM Table_A and (inner) join her with Table_B... Then there is a question how to join this two table (based on what?)? And the answer is ON Table_A.ShopLot and Table_B.ShopLot fields. Take a row from Table_A, see value of ShopLot field and find all rows with that value (if there is) in Table_B and join them. Table_C is joined the same way only name of fields is changed.

Than the third step is to make WHERE clause. This is probably the easiest part because we now have one large table and we just need to say what we need

```
WHERE Table_A.UnitTypeID='PAD' AND Table_B.UnitType.ID='FROG' 
  AND Table_C.PartTypeID='FLIES'
```

And that's it. I tried to make it simple as i could. I bet there is much bather explanation online just need to do a little search...

Here is a complete code:

```
SELECT Table_A.ID, Table_A.UnitTypeID, Table_A.ShopLot, Table_B.ID, Table_B.UnitTypeID,
         Table_B.ContainerRef, Table_C.ID, Table_C.PartTypeID
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.ShopLot = Table_B.ShopLot
INNER JOIN Table_C
ON Table_B.ContainerRef = Table_C.ContainerId

WHERE Table_A.UnitTypeID='PAD' AND Table_B.UnitType.ID='FROG' 
  AND Table_C.PartTypeID='FLIES'
```

I hope this help a little bit it's not complicated as it's look at first. It would be better if example be with two table but it is what it is. GL

Answer (score 0):

Александр Миладинович managed to simplify to the point of "easy" something I had given up on as too advanced to consider.

The only thing left for me to determine is how to convince MySQL to do For Each Row as with SQL-Server, and I can move back to learning at a reasonable pace.

Comment: I'm not quite understand what you want to do For Each Row. What's the goal? To insert, update and based on what? Let's say if you want to update (one) field in each row where (some) field value is 5 you simple do that with UPDATE table SET this_field = new_value WHERE  some_field_value = 5; Maybe you should edit you question and explain better what's the result you want to achieve.