# Specific query between multiple tables using foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database project for school and I'm relatively new at SQL queries in a class so I was looking for help on a specific query.

Here's my schema :

```
movies
----------------------------
id:integer (primary key)
title: varchar(100) 
--------------------------

stars
--------------------------
id:integer (primary key)
--------------------------

stars_in_movies
---------------------------------------
star_id:integer, referencing stars.id
movie_id:integer, referencing movies.id
-----------------------------------------
```

So, provided a star's ID, what would be the query to get title of all the movies a star was in?

I know that this is a pretty specific question for a query, but I was wondering if someone could provide a specific query and an explanation as to why the query does what it does, as I'm more interested in the "why the query works" aspect of the answer.

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Hi to solve this you should start with understanding of JOIN syntax you could do that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) also you can take a look one of my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153032/how-to-test-in-and-between-each-of-several-tables/29157204#29157204) where i tried to explain JOIN syntax piece by piece... also you should read something about Many-To-Many relationship in mySql...

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic oh perfect! The explanation on the other post is perfect, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) glad I could help a little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table as

```
select
m.id,
m.title
from movies m
join stars_in_movies sm on sm.movie_id = m.id
join stars s on s.id = sm.star_id
where s.id = {your star id to be searched}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.title from
stars_in_movies sim join movies m
on m.id=sim.movie_id
where sim.star_id = 1
```

Connect this table give you title of film where star play. Check link: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e876/6/0)