# Compare values in two columns and display the matched rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables s1 and s2,

s1 contains

```
id   length
500    25
504    43
601    30
401    31
```

s2 contains

```
id   length
401   31
504   43
601   30
500   80
```

I should write a query in such a way that it should retrieve the rows only with matching values ids and length.

Comment: That is the most basic join. Please take a SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
SELECT * FROM s1,s2 WHERE s1.id = s2.id;
```

This is the basic of MySQL. You should start learn about this and stop to asking this type of questions.

Comment: He definitely should use JOIN statement rather than do that on the old way.. GL

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.length
FROM s1
INNER JOIN s2
ON s1.id = s2.id AND s1.length = s2.length
```

I understand that you should return value where and id and length match...

So it's simpe INNER JOIN statement on two field...

GL!

Edit:

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0144d/2) for that to see how it's work...

And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) you can learn a little more about JOIN in SQL

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153032/how-to-test-in-and-between-each-of-several-tables/29157204#29157204) is one my other answer where i tried to explain step by step how JOIN work hope that can help a little... So GL again.